# How does my android activity knows when the device changes in orientation

Tags: android

Can you please tell me how does my android activity know (is there a callback) when there is a change in screen orientation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `Activity`'s `public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29

Watch out for this:

> Note that this will only be called if you have selected configurations you would like to handle with the configChanges attribute in your manifest.